# The ui router resolve result data is not injected in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-http

In my SchoolyearController the parameter schoolyears is undefined.

How can I retrieve my schoolyears objects in the schoolyearService and inject the result into the SchoolyearController?

**SERVICE**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('schoolyear').service('schoolyearService', function ($http) {

    return {
        getSchoolyears: function () {            
            var path = 'scripts/model/schoolyears.json';
            $http.get(path).then(function (response) {
                return response.data.schoolyears;  // The schoolyears here are the 6 expected JS objects in an array, so far so good but how do I get those objects into the SchoolyearController as parameter ?
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UI-ROUTER**

```
resolve: {
    schoolyearService: ['schoolyearService',
        function (schoolyearService) {
            return schoolyearService.getSchoolyears();
        }]
},
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('schoolyear').controller('SchoolyearController', function ($scope, schoolyears) {

    $scope.schoolyears = schoolyears; // I do not want to do a $http request here I just want to get passed the data here !!!
});
```

**UPDATE**

Still the schoolyears in the resolved property are undefined, why?

**FACTORY**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('schoolyearModule').factory('schoolyearFactory', function ($http) {

    return {
        getSchoolyears: function () {
            var path = 'scripts/model/schoolyears.json';
            $http.get(path).then(function (response) {
                return response.data.schoolyears;  // The schoolyears here are the 6 expected JS objects in an array
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UI-ROUTER**

```
resolve: {
    schoolyears: function(schoolyearFactory) {
        var schoolyears = schoolyearFactory.getSchoolyears();
        return schoolyears;
    }

},
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('schoolyearModule').controller('ProjectsController', function ($scope, schoolyears) {

    $scope.schoolyears = schoolyears; // I do not want to do a $http request here I just want to get passed the data here !!!
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resolved value is named `schoolyearService` (and thus clashes with the service which has the same name):

```
resolve: {
    schoolyearService: ...
```

But you're trying to inject it using the name `schoolyears`:

```
angular.module('schoolyear').controller('SchoolyearController', 
    function ($scope, schoolyears) {
```

Use the same name (`schoolyears`) everywhere:

```
resolve: {
    schoolyears: ...
```

Also, you should use the factory() method to define your service, and not the servoce() method. The `service()` method takes a constructor function as argument, not a function returning an object being the actual service instance.

EDIT:

Moreover, you're not returning anything from the `getSchoolyears()` service method. So `undefined` is returned. What you need is:

```
    getSchoolyears: function () {
        var path = 'scripts/model/schoolyears.json';
        return $http.get(path).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.schoolyears;
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with corrected code snippets, but still the schoolyearFactory returns undefined schoolyear objects. In the SchoolyearFactory itself the response.data.schoolyears objects are the 6 JS objects I have put in the schoolyears.json file as test data.

Comment: OK I thought its enough to call the $http and do only a return inside the response callback...Thanks a bunch it worked!